# Logic App HTTP action - Sharepoint REST API - Managed Identity - 401 unauthorized error

Tags: sharepoint, azure-logic-apps, azure-managed-identity, azure-http-trigger

Geniuses

I have been fighting with this for a few days now, I have had no problem authenticating and assigning a user assigned managed identity in Logic Apps using the Graph api and graph explorer however, I am now trying to do the same for SharePoint v1 rest api (not the graph api) and cannot make it work... Here is what the trigger looks like:

[image]

I have successfully granted app access to the SharePoint site (through graph explorer) and confirmed that the user assigned identity permissions are configured with consent for both graph and SharePoint online:

[image]

I can't figure out why the Managed Identity won't work on the SharePoint API...

Has anyone gotten this to work?

Thanks in advance...

Lee